# CakePhp Can´t Redirect beforeFilter

Tags: redirect, cakephp, before-filter

I am making a website with a backoffice login and register page. I am using UsersController and PostsController and I can´t access my main page website because it redirects me to my login page. I made a before filter and placed in UsersController:

```
use Cake\Event\Event;

public function beforeFilter(Event $event){
            $this->Auth->allow(['register', 'home']);
        }
```

Comment: add the line in `PostsController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in `PostsController.php`

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event){
    $this->Auth->allow(['home']);
}
```